# Xamarin Android Facebook Login

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, xamarin

I'm using Xamarin Android with Visual Studio, and I am trying to use the facebook sdk to do native login. I have managed to use Xamarin.Auth however, this presents a webview which I do not want to use if the user has the facebook app.

I am using Xamarin Android Player

So far I have completed the following:
Intalled the facebook Android SDK 
Created a facebook app
Installed the facebook apk on the android player

I have also updated the androidmanifest.xml as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="FacebookExperiment.FacebookExperiment" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <application android:label="FacebookExperiment" android:icon="@drawable/Icon"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
          android:configChanges=
                 "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
          android:label="@string/app_name" />
</manifest>
```

I've also included my appID in the strings.xml. At this point everything builds fine and I can deploy the application to the Xamarin Android Player.

The next step I took was to use the facebook login button, so I updated the my Main.xml to below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Hello" />
  <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I got the details from  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3.

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        int count = 1;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            FacebookSdk.SdkInitialize(ApplicationContext);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);


            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

            button.Click += delegate { button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++); };
        }
    }
```

Now when I build I don't receive any errors, when I deploy to Xamarin Android Player I receive an Unhandled Exception in Visual Studio- The call stack doesn't provide with much information (I can't seem to copy it ).

The output:

```
06-11 05:54:28.522 D/        ( 3987): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9fec50c0, tid 4013
06-11 05:54:28.534 D/libEGL  ( 3987): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_xap.so
06-11 05:54:28.539 D/libEGL  ( 3987): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_xap.so
06-11 05:54:28.554 I/OpenGLRenderer( 3987): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-11 05:54:28.576 E/OpenGLRenderer( 3987): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
06-11 05:54:28.576 E/OpenGLRenderer( 3987): MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
06-11 05:54:28.579 E/OpenGLRenderer( 3987): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
06-11 05:54:28.580 E/OpenGLRenderer( 3987): MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
06-11 05:54:28.580 D/OpenGLRenderer( 3987): Enabling debug mode 0
06-11 05:54:28.606 W/EGL_xap ( 3987): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-11 05:54:28.606 W/OpenGLRenderer( 3987): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9fe0ac80, error=EGL_SUCCESS
Thread started:  #2
06-11 05:54:28.661 D/Mono    ( 3987): DllImport attempting to load: '/system/lib/libc.so'.
06-11 05:54:28.661 D/Mono    ( 3987): DllImport loaded library '/system/lib/libc.so'.
06-11 05:54:28.661 D/Mono    ( 3987): DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/libc.so' ('/system/lib/libc.so').
06-11 05:54:28.661 D/Mono    ( 3987): Searching for 'gettid'.
06-11 05:54:28.661 D/Mono    ( 3987): Probing 'gettid'.
06-11 05:54:28.661 D/Mono    ( 3987): Found as 'gettid'.
An unhandled exception occured.

06-11 05:54:32.333 E/AndroidRuntime( 3987): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
06-11 05:54:32.333 E/AndroidRuntime( 3987): Process: FacebookExperiment.FacebookExperiment, PID: 3987
06-11 05:54:32.333 E/AndroidRuntime( 3987): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Object.hashCode()' on a null object reference
06-11 05:54:32.333 E/AndroidRuntime( 3987):     at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:746)
06-11 05:54:32.333 E/AndroidRuntime( 3987):     at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(ConcurrentHashMap.java:774)
06-11 05:54:32.333 E/AndroidRuntime( 3987):     at com.facebook.internal.Utility.queryAppSettings(Utility.java:825)
06-11 05:54:32.333 E/AndroidRuntime( 3987):     at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$1.run(LoginButton.java:486)
06-11 05:54:32.333 E/AndroidRuntime( 3987):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-11 05:54:32.333 E/AndroidRuntime( 3987):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
06-11 05:54:32.333 E/AndroidRuntime( 3987):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
06-11 05:54:36.066 I/Process ( 3987): Sending signal. PID: 3987 SIG: 9
```

I'm not sure why this is crashing at this point, have I missed something for button to fail ?

Comment: This is a wild stab in the dark, but looking at that stack trace, it seems the error originates [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/30f5984bbc2c2f68717aa88b2b583a67b6b28d99/facebook/src/com/facebook/internal/Utility.java#L825). Can you place a breakpoint at that line and see if `applicateionId != null`? I am not sure why this would happen, but just to be sure, you could also double check that `facebook_app_id` is set correctly in `strings.xml`

Comment: In order to be able to debug that, you may have to add the [Facebook Android SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk) source code to the classpath of your debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all ensure that you target above API 15, you have the correct facebook api key and you have installed all the required packages the facebook component requires.

Your `OnCreate` method should look something like this:

```
protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FacebookSdk.SdkInitialize(ApplicationContext);
        AppEventsLogger.ActivateApp(Application);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);


        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

        button.Click += delegate { button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++); };
    }
```

You will have to create your hash key(debug and release). [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started) is everything you need. You will just have to translate it from Java to C# which is quite easy. Hope I helped you.